# How to find the days between dates using my code?

Tags: java, sql, date

Below is my code which checks the date which is stored in database with the current system date and calculates the days and if that days is lesser than the 180 days it will print something else print nothing,this code works great in an normal java program(with out using swings concept) if it is used with the swing program i changed the sql query to check get the date from the database based on the department and staff names which is entered in the text fields,i coded this code inside an jbutton,in the output it just prints the current system date but not calculates the days between the selected date and the current system dates,friends this is the problem am facing kindly need your help friends....thanks in advance..

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/leave", "root", "");
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from staff where depmt='" + txt1 + "' AND staffs='" + txt2 + "'");
        Calendar javaCalendar = null;
        String currentDate = "";
        javaCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentDate = javaCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (javaCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + javaCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int cdate = javaCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int cmonth = (javaCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        int cyear = javaCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int z = 0;
        int date = 0, month = 0, year = 0;

        System.out.println("Current Date\t" + currentDate);
        System.out.println("\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
            date = rs.getInt(3);
            month = rs.getInt(4);
            year = rs.getInt(5);
            System.out.println("Random Date\t" + date + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\n");
            int d = (date - cdate);
            int m = month - cmonth;
            int y = year - cyear;
            int d1 = java.lang.Math.abs(d);
            int d2 = java.lang.Math.abs(m);
            int d3 = java.lang.Math.abs(y);
            z = d1 + (d2 * 30) + (d3 * 365);
            if (z >= 180) {
                System.out.println("something");
                0
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Since you might do it the same way in a command line app. or servlet as a Swing app., it seems Swing is not really relevant to this question.  Removed tag.

Comment: substract timestamp, not day/month/year.

Comment: ..and stop with those ridiculous edits.  :-/

Comment: Andre Thompson in java swing application only i didn't get my expected output but in command line am getting it whats the problem with that swing tag

Comment: Show the code of the command line app. as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21631624/edit).

Comment: @devbj. That's because you changed stuff when you converted to swing, not because of Swing. Also, use Calendar to do the math for you. That's the puropse of Calendar.

Comment: Also note, my name is not 'Andre'.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use prepared statements cause this way your query is prone to sql injections.
Date formatter insted of concating string for currentdate

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

Also it seems like your not closeing the connection that may be another issue.
Is there any reason for storeing the date in 3 separate columns?

Comment: yes so that it will be easy for the calculation thats it and thus i can get the days

Comment: Just use the calender to do your operations. Referece http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-calendar.html

Comment: Do u have any link where i can get a reference for how to calculate days from the stored date with the current system date..

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm to calculate the day difference between two dates is broken. It does not take in account different month lengths or leap years.

Unfortunately Java `Calendar` does not offer this feature at all. So either you apply your own homegrown algorithm (not easy, but in web there are some sources how to map a gregorian date to epoch days) or you use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) like this way:

```
LocalDate db = new LocalDate(year, month, date);
int days = Days.daysBetween(db, LocalDate.now()).getDays();
```

Note that the result will be negative if db date is in the future. After all you can greatly shorten your code and abandon all Calendar stuff which is very bad for calculations of durations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by changing return value from millisecond to day.

```
public static int daysBetween(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo){
      return (int)( (dateTo.getTime() - dateFrom.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 Date date1 = df.parse("14/02/2014");
 Date date2 = df.parse("08/03/2014");
 int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Start Of Day

If you start with a mid-afternoon date-time object, go back 180 days by calculating seconds * minutes * hours * 180, you'll end up excluding the date-times earlier in that day 180 ago whereas I suppose you would want to include them. You should pay attention to when the day begins.

## Time Zone

Both the question and other answers ignore the issue of time zone. Time zone defines the beginning of a day. Given the point about start of day (above), time zone is a related component.

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

Note that while a Joda-Time DateTime object is similar to a java.util.Date, a DateTime does truly know its own assigned time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeInQuestion = new DateTime( 2013, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, timeZone );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime hundredEightyDaysAgo = now.minusDays( 180 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
boolean isExpired = dateTimeInQuestion.isBefore( hundredEightyDaysAgo );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeInQuestion: " + dateTimeInQuestion );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "hundredEightyDaysAgo: " + hundredEightyDaysAgo );
System.out.println( "isExpired: " + isExpired );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInQuestion: 2013-06-05T04:03:02.000+02:00
now: 2014-03-10T07:34:26.937+01:00
hundredEightyDaysAgo: 2013-09-11T00:00:00.000+02:00
isExpired: true
```